# how to disable automatic dos mode?

Tags: init-file, mode-line, linux

Many versions ago, if you opened a dos-line-end file on Linux you would see the extra `^M` codes. Now it automatically recognizes the situation and puts "DOS" in the info bar and hides the extra `^M`s.

How can I exit "DOS" mode and switch back to Unix mode? How can I disable the auto-detection and force the files to be opened with Unix line endings and the DOS CR shown as `^M`?

Comment: So that none of us get confused, if the original poster could please verify what `major-mode` and what `minor-modes` are active in the buffer -- i.e., type `M-x describe-mode` and update the question with said information.  In addition, please consider including a screen-shot and/or some detailed description as to what is meant by "**hides the extra codes**".  At first read, I thought perhaps this has to do with a simple `M-x fundamental-mode` to exit whatever major-mode exists; and, I thought about deleting entry from the `auto-mode-alist` -- but now, I'm thinking just line endings dos/unix?

Comment: Are you asking how to return to the buffer `^M` codes when opening dos-line-end file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EndOfLineTips

> You can reopen the file with the correct line ending with a command like `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system utf-8-dos`. If your file is not in Unicode, be sure to specify the correct encoding system instead of `utf-8-dos`

Dos uses `CR+LF` end of line, when UNIX uses only `LF`. `CR` sometimes looks like `^M`. For viewing `^M` you must use `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system utf-8-unix`. This will use `LF` as end of line and indicate `CR` like `^M` instead of Dos which uses `CR+LF` as end of line.

Disable autodetect: not sure it needs. If you want to convert files into UNIX format, then open DOS file and set line ending with `M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system utf-8-unix`, this command will convert all `CR+LF` into `LF`.

If you can edit the file, you could open file with a certain coding system with `-*- coding: utf-8-unix; -*-` at the first or second line in the file.

Comment: `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` is exactly what i was after. I would like to have that applied automatically though.   I guess there isn't really a compelling reason for it except that I only occasionally encounter dos files and I was used to that obvious visual cue of all the `^M`'s when I open one.

Answer (score 3):

[(emacs) Recognize Coding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recognize-Coding.html)

> Emacs recognizes which kind of end-of-line conversion to use based
>   on the contents of the file: if it sees only carriage-returns, or only
>   carriage-return linefeed sequences, then it chooses the end-of-line
>   conversion accordingly.  You can inhibit the automatic use of
>   end-of-line conversion by setting the variable
>   `inhibit-eol-conversion` to non-`nil`.  If you do that, DOS-style
>   files will be displayed with the `^M` characters visible in the
>   buffer; some people prefer this to the more subtle `(DOS)` end-of-line
>   type indication near the left edge of the mode line (see [eol-mnemonic](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mode-Line.html)).